# SQL server Query help

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am passing a list of zipcodes to a stored proc (say 11111, 11112, 11113, 11114, 11115) and the zip code table contains only few rows (say 11111, 11112, 11113) and now I want to write a query which returns the zip codes that are not exists in the table (11114 and 11115)

Could anyone please help me to write a query like this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how do you pass that list of ZIP codes into your stored proc??

Comment: you want to compare a list of zip codes to the list you have in the database and end up with a list of zip codes not in your database?

Answer (score 2):

Not knowing your exact implementation, this quick and dirty query should be adaptable to what you're trying.  Select the zip codes from the list you passed which aren't in the full table of zip codes:

```
SELECT ZipCode 
FROM PassedList 
WHERE ZipCode NOT IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT ZipCode
  FROM ZipCodeTable
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have use a `JOIN` to build your first query.

Now you'll need a RIGHT JOIN/WHERE to include all items in your zip list which correspondent record on zip table is `null`

**EDIT:** Here is a sample

```
CREATE TABLE ZipCodesTable(Code int NOT NULL)
CREATE TABLE ZipCodesList (Code int NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO ZipCodesTable (Code) VALUES (11111)
INSERT INTO ZipCodesTable (Code) VALUES (11112)
INSERT INTO ZipCodesTable (Code) VALUES (11113)

INSERT INTO ZipCodesList  (Code) VALUES (11111)
INSERT INTO ZipCodesList  (Code) VALUES (11112)
INSERT INTO ZipCodesList  (Code) VALUES (11113)
INSERT INTO ZipCodesList  (Code) VALUES (11114)
INSERT INTO ZipCodesList  (Code) VALUES (11115)

SELECT ZipCodesList.Code
  FROM ZipCodesTable RIGHT
  JOIN ZipCodesList
    ON ZipCodesTable.Code = ZipCodesList.Code
 WHERE ZipCodesTable.Code IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This article uses CTE to take your string of entries, convert to a table so you can include in a query:  http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/CTE/67974/

Comment: You need to register at the website to view the article as an FYI for those interested. Fight the power!

Comment: My bad. I thought it was like SO.

Answer (score 0):

No need to create a table in SQL use a temp table in the stored proc. If you need to pass in the zips as string use this. If you have a table valued parameter you can pass them in as a table.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE spCheckZip
@Zips varchar(256)  --space delimited list of zips

AS

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ZipCheck') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #ZipCheck
CREATE TABLE #ZipCheck (zipcode string) --Note string not int for zips with leading 0's.

IF CharIndex(' ',@Zips) > 1
BEGIN

   Declare @StartPos as int
   Declare @ZipCd As Varchar(16)

   set @StartPos = 2
   set  @ZipCd = substring(@Zips,1,CharIndex(',',@Zips))
   WHILE @StartPos > 1 and @StartPos < Len(@Zips)
   BEGIN
      INSERT Into #ZipCheck (zipcode) 
      SELECT Substring(@ZipCd,1,len(@ZipCd)-1)
      SET @StartPos = charindex(',',@Zips, @StartPos)+1
      SET @ZipCd = substring(@Zips,@StartPos,CharIndex(',',@Zips))
   END
END

SELECT ZipCode 
FROM ZipCheck LEFT JOIN YourZipTable on ZipCheck.zipcode=YourZipTable.YourZipField
WHERE YourZipTable.YourZipField IS NULL
```